# Running a web app from the iPad home screen as an iPhone web app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, web-applications, web

A few weeks ago while developing a web app for iPhone/iPad, I tried adding it to the iPad's home screen. When I launched it, it launched as an iPhone app running on an iPad (portrait with the 1x/2x magnifier).

Try as I might, I can't recreate whatever caused this to happen. Is it something I specify in metatags, the splash screen, or something to do with page widths? I can't find anything online about it.

Comment: Have you bundled this up into an app using something like Phonegap?

Comment: No, it's a web app that the user adds to their phone using 'Add to Home Screen'.